# Bittrex api market change calculation

Tags: cryptocurrency

Does anyone know how Bittrex calculates the market change (shown in the image) and which values i can use to replicate it

Using the "Last Price" from https://api.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-fsn gives me a different value

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks that "PrevDay" field in API response reflects the price exactly 24 hours ago. Same for some other exchanges and data providers.

Actually % change on website should be based on same, but this may depend on how often data is refreshed in browser.

Answer (score 0):

This percentage sign shows how much % market has been chnaged in last 24 hours

```
Like prev btc price=8000 and new btc price =8500
so market change 8500-8000=(500/8000)*100=6.25%
```